# I need Products to always be instock and manage inventory. Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, magento-community, inventory

My business is 50/50 drop shipped or products that I have in my inventory.

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to show all the products as in stock and I also need to be able to manage the inventory that I do have.

From what I have seen in the configuration I can either manager the inventory or show my product in-stock.

Is there a solution or recommendation that would help me with this issue that I have.

Thank you for your time to read and suggest.

Norris

Answer (score 1):

We have the exact same situation re drop ship vs in-house products. We handle things a bit differently as some of our inventory numbers must be real and accurate, but others are always available even if they are momentarily out of stock with our supplier.

This isn't really elegant, but you could:

- add 5000 to the actual inventory count for each product.
- set Notify for Quantity Below to 5001, 5005, whatever suits you. (Admin->Inventory(under catalog))
- Leave Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock set to 0.

That would keep everything appearing to be in-stock, and you would be able to easily see your real stock levels by subtracting the "hard deck" of 5000. (Thanks Top Gun)

I think that would work for you, but if I have misinterpreted your need post again with more info.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I took a different approach.

If you set all items to Instock and at the same time change Backorders to allow for qty below 0. It will prevent the manage stock from changing the stock availability to Out of Stock. Upside you can always add items to carts regardless of whether they are in stock. Downside is that the stock availability is now useless for anyother purpose because its not actually tracking 0 vs non-zero items.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest you to make new attribute for example you can named it: "real_inventory". You can attach it to all products and after that there you can store the information about inventory of the product. After that you can set all products to have quantity equal to 100000 or some other big number. Hope that will help you to resolve your problem.

Good luck.