# I need Products to always be instock and manage inventory. Magento ver. 2.2.3

Tags: inventory

In my business, we do 50/50 dropshipping. I need to manage inventory within Magento but at the same time when inventory hits 0, I still need the product to stay In Stock because I will drop ship it.

Any way to do this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/53020/2543 this approach may suit you if you want to manage inventory + still never go out of stock

Comment: Thanks! However I need to dropshipper to get notified and if I set everything to 5k they won't get notified